# Selenium IDE: verifying the maxlength of a textbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, maxlength

Good day.

I am new to Selenium IDE and I am trying to test the maxlength of a textbox. In the given scenario the textbox should accept a max of 50 alphanumeric characters.

The HTML file indicates id="username" value maxlength="20".

In my Selenium IDE test case:
Command: store attribute |
Target: id=username@value maxlength |
Value: 50

My test case passed even though I am expecting it to fail. I would just like to ask if my approach is wrong or if there is a better way to test the maxlength of a textbox.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `assertAttribute` command as follows:

```
assertAttribute | id=myTextField@maxlength | 20
```

Replace '`id=myTextField`' above with the appropriate locator, and '`20`' with the expected max length.